# Proving determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I need to show that by

$D\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\ c&d\end{pmatrix}=ad-bc$ a determinant is given.
Also to show that every determinant must satisfy equation
$D\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\ c&d\end{pmatrix}= ad − bc$
By writing the columns of the matrix as $\begin{pmatrix}a\\c\end{pmatrix}= ae_1 + ce_2$ and $\begin{pmatrix}b\\d\end{pmatrix}= be_1 + de_2$

I have to use these properties

$\det (a_1,\ldots,a_{j-1},a_j+ b, a_{j+1},\ldots,a_n)=\det(a_1,\ldots,a_n)+ \det (a_1,\ldots,a_{j1},b,a_{j+1},\ldots,a_n) $
$\forall 1\leqslant j \leqslant n, a_1,\ldots,a_n,
b\in  R^n $,

$\det (a_1,\ldots,a_{j1},ra_j,a_{j+1},\ldots,a_n)= r \det (a_1,\ldots,a_n) $
$\forall 1\leqslant j \leqslant n, a_1,\ldots,a_n,
b\in  R^n, r\in R $

$\det (a_1,\ldots,a_n)= 0$ when $(\exists1 \leqslant i< j \leqslant n : a_i= a_j)$

$\det (e_1,\ldots, e_n) = \det E = 1$.

In case 1 do I just substitute $a,b,c,d$ with $a_1...$? What does it mean a determinant is given?
The second ask I am completely lost, so if anyone can explain this simply I will be very thankful!

Comment: Yes, of course. Actually a matrix is a collection of column vector, so you just have to write $D(Yourmatrix)=D(Column1,Column2)$, decomposing your vector according to your rules is so sufficient to demonstrate the wanted formula. Yet, note that you formula are not $ det(1,...,n)$ but $det(a_1,...,a_n)$ with $a_i$ are vectors. Note that determinant always take a serie of vector as arguments but do not take a serie of real or complex number.

Comment: So by asking me to show that a determinant is given I need to write the properties like this: $det(a_a, a_b, a_c, a_d)$??

Comment: Yes that's it. You've well rewrite your equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The determinant of your matrix is given by
$$ \det \begin{pmatrix} a&b\\ c&d\end{pmatrix} = \det(\begin{pmatrix} a \\c\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} b \\d\end{pmatrix}) = \det(ae_1+ce_2, be_1+d e_2)$$ where $$ e_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\0\end{pmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad e_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\1\end{pmatrix}$$

Remember you have the following properties (in this special case) :
$$ \det(e_1,e_2)=1$$
$$ \det(e_2,e_1) = -\det(e_1,e_2) = -1 $$
$$ \det(e_1,e_1)=0$$
$$ \det(e_2,e_2)=0$$

Then you just need to expand and use the properties :

\begin{align}  
\det(a e_1 + ce_2, b e_1 + d e_2) &= \det(a e_1,b e_1) + \det(a e_1,d e_2) + \det(ce_2, b e_1) + \det(ce_2,d e_2)\\  
&=  ab\det(e_1,e_1) + ad\det(e_1,e_2) + bc\det(e_2, e_1) + cd\det(e_2,e_2)\\
&=  0 + ad \det(e_1, e_2) + bc  \det(e_2, e_1) + 0\\
&=   ad \det(e_1, e_2) - bc  \det(e_1, e_2)\\
&= ad - bc
\end{align}

Comment: $\det(e_2,e_1)=-\det(e_1,e_2)$ is not one of the properties you can use directly. (It is not in the list of properties given in the question.) It should at least be proven before it is used. For example as follows: $0=\det(e_1+e_2,e_1+e_2)$ $=\det(e_1,e_1)+\det(e_1,e_2)+\det(e_2,e_1)+\det(e_2,e_2)$ $=\det(e_1,e_2)+\det(e_2,e_1).$

Comment: Indeed @ReinhardMeier

Comment: Thank you! Just one more thing do I need to rewrite the 4 properties, but as $det(a_a, a_b, a_c, a_d)$ for the first part where I need to show that a determinant is given? Or am I mixing something up?